# How to retrieve one row/one field using PHP mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, row

Just started learning PHP, Angular and mySQL and am trying to retrieve just one field value from one single row. The same code below works for a query that returns multiples rows:

```
$qry = "SELECT ID FROM SharePoint001 ORDER BY DownloadedTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1"; //returns a5f415a7-3d4f-11e5-b52f-b82a72d52c35        
$data = array();   
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $data[] = array("ID" => $rows['ID']);
}
print_r(json_encode($data[0]));
```

Comment: Tip: Don't start by learning `mysql_*` functions, they are obsolete.

Comment: You need a `where` clause: `SELECT ID FROM SharePoint001 WHERE something = 'somethingelse' ORDER BY DownloadedTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Also if it's supposed to be specific, you will want to choose a unique column for the `where`

Comment: According to this code snippet, this sql is not executed. So you want get any value. please be specific and publish the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not executed the query, so you'll never get results.

1. First you have to prepare query and place it into a variable lets say `$qry`.
2. Then **execute** that query by using *mysql_query()* function and capture result into a **variable** lets say `$result`
3. Now you can **iterate** that `$result` with loop to fetch **rows** and **cells** (what you call fields).

Below is code I have corrected:

```
$qry = "SELECT ID FROM SharePoint001 ORDER BY DownloadedTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = mysql_query($qry); // You are missing this line

$data = array();   
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // You have to pass result into mysql_fetch_array not query string 
{
    $data[] = array("ID" => $rows['ID']);
}
print_r(json_encode($data[0]));
```

Comment: Nice answer, but as already suggested by @Alexander O'mara, don't use mysql (obsolete), use mysqli instead.

Comment: Yes I suggest the same, But as there is not much difference for basic learner between mysql and mysqli, for learning purpose it is okay but better is to go with mysqli from very start.

Comment: oh crap, yes I had that line in the other portion of my code. Sorry Friday night finishing up work. Sorry about that. Thanks for the tip and yes I was confused about mysqli and there is also PDO? anyways thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend switching to the `mysqli` extension. It's a much better way of doing things and you will probably find it much easier.

> **Here's a simple mysqli solution for you:**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table WHERE 1');
$row = $resource->fetch_assoc();
echo "{$row['field']}";
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

> **If you're grabbing more than one row, I do it like this:**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table WHERE 1');
while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "{$row['field']}";
}
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

> **With Error Handling:** If there is a fatal error the script will terminate with an error message.

```
// ini_set('display_errors',1); // Uncomment to show errors to the end user.
if ( $db->connect_errno ) die("Database Connection Failed: ".$db->connect_error);
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
$resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table WHERE 1');
if ( !$resource ) die('Database Error: '.$db->error);
while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "{$row['field']}";
}
$resource->free();
$db->close();
```

> **With try/catch exception handling:** This lets you deal with any errors all in one place and possibly continue execution when something fails, if that's desired.

```
try {
    if ( $db->connect_errno ) throw new Exception("Connection Failed: ".$db->connect_error);
    $db = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');
    $resource = $db->query('SELECT field FROM table WHERE 1');
    if ( !$resource ) throw new Exception($db->error);
    while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo "{$row['field']}";
    }
    $resource->free();
    $db->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "DB Exception: ",$e->getMessage(),"\n";
}
```

> **The MySQL extension is:**

- **Officially [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)** (as of PHP 5.5. [Will be removed in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql).)
- Lacks an object-oriented interface
- Much slower than `mysqli`
- Not under active development

> **Does not support:**

- Non-blocking, asynchronous queries
- Transactions
- Stored procedures
- Multiple Statements
- [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or parameterized queries
- The "new" password authentication method (on by default in MySQL 5.6; required in 5.7+)

Since it is deprecated, using it makes your code less future proof. See [**the comparison of SQL extensions**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).